# Is it possible to connect to snowflake in Azure Databricks using Oauth token from an existing Service Principal?

Tags: azure-active-directory, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-databricks, azure-service-principal

I am trying to connect to Snowflake in Databricks using an Azure access token generated from an existing Service Principal (not using the documentation's method to create one as I don't have the permissions to). Currently I am receiving the error "Invalid OAuth access token".

I believe the solution is I need snowflake to grant access to the service principal, however not sure how to do this or if it is even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this Snowflake document](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-security-fed-auth-use.html#native-sso-okta-only), programmatic SSO with Federated Authentication (like you would need in a Databricks notebook) is only available for the Okta identity provider - even though Microsoft Azure Active Directory *is* among their [supported Identity Providers](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-security-fed-auth-overview.html#supported-identity-providers)